# Unable to access class variables inside for loop

Tags: apex, json

Not sure how to assign c.accountId to accountId inside myList. Also please suggest when to use `{get;set;}` for variables. I have seen some forums using it and some not. My requirement here is to post `varMap` to external server in JSON

```
public class Vars{
   public Id caseId;
   public list<myList> rel_acc_info; 
}

public class myList {
   public Id accountId;
   public string accountName;
}

list<Vars> vars = new list<Vars>();
map<Id, Vars> varMap = new map<Id,vars>();

for(case c: [Select Id, accountId, account.name from case limit 10]){
   vars v = new vars();
   v.caseId = c.Id;
   v.rel_acc_info = new list<myList>();
   rel_acc_info.accountId = c.accountId;
   rel_acc_info.accountName = c.account.name;
}
```

> Error: Variable does not exist: rel_acc_info.accountId

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating a list of Vars and not a List of <Account>?

Comment: Hi EricSSH, I tried to put a prototype of my actual requirement as my actual code is too lengthy. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off you're missing the v. qualifier, i.e. `rel_acc_info.accountId` should be `v.rel_acc_info.accountId` The other issus is that rel_acc_info is a list, but you are trying to assign to is as if it was a single instance, you need to create a myList item and add that to the array, e.g.

```
for(case c: [Select Id, accountId, account.name from case limit 10]) {
   vars v = new vars();
   v.caseId = c.Id;
   v.rel_acc_info = new list<myList>();
   myList ml = new myList()
   ml.accountId = c.accountId;
   ml.accountName = c.account.name;
   v.rel_acc_info.Add(ml)
}
```

[its not totally clear from your question/code why rel_acc_info is a list, so perhaps the real fix is to update vars to have a single instance of MyList, rather than a list]

Comment: Perfectly worked. Thanks superfell for the suggestion and solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have no property rel_acc_info alone as it is part to `v`

Also, not sure the structure of the surrounding method for the for loop so adjust as necessary

so either

```
   v.rel_acc_info.accountId = c.accountId;
   v.rel_acc_info.accountName = c.account.name
```

or

```
list<myList> rel_acc_info = v.rel_acc_info;
rel_acc_info.accountId = c.accountId;
rel_acc_info.accountName = c.account.name
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried both your suggestions, but still getting the same error: variable doesnot exist: myList.

Comment: @pmvsdt - That is a different error as now you are talking about mylist. **you will need to adjust since you did not provide all your code**  Without the rest of your code you are on your own to figure out the proper references.